# DropDownList loses its property after using updatePanel in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have below code to have intelligent dropdownlist in asp.net to have the search property there

```
<script type="text/javascript"> $(".chzn-select").chosen(); $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true }); </script>
```

The problem is that whenever I use updatepanel in this way:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" >
    <ContentTemplate>
        <fieldset>
        </fieldset>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

after that: it loses its property and returned as normal dropdownlist. Any idea how to fix this and make the update panel do not recreate the dropdownlist to its previous property?!

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute that script again after an UpdatePanel update. Since the DOM still changes and the browsers loses the script bindings. You can use the `PageRequestManager` for that.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();

    //for after an updatepanel update
    prm.add_endRequest(function () {
        buildDropDownList();
    });

    //for normal page load
    buildDropDownList();

    function buildDropDownList() {
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
        $(".chzn-select-deselect").chosen({ allow_single_deselect: true });
    }
</script>
```